# copy a file and change its permissions in Linux with C

Tags: c, linux, permissions, copy

I copy a file by opening the source in read-only mode and the destination in write-only mode. It's simple and it works.

The problem is that sometimes I am copying a file that sits on an NFS drive, or other network drives and when in these cases the permissions get all screwed and SELinux complains. I then go and manually set the permissions of the files I just copied and it's OK. I can access them again (via ftp, web, etc).

Is there any way to copy a file and change the permissions to a certain user and group?

Code is appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:

would something like

```
open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)
```

work?

Comment: Do you mean change the _permissions_ (`rwxrwxrwx`), or change the _ownership_ (user and group)?

Comment: david: either. I mean, I tried with chown user:group and I tried chmod 666 and also works...

Comment: You probably don't want 0666; that leaves the file publicly writable which is usually a mistake.  I'd recommend 0644; I'd accept 0664.  I'm glad you didn't say 0777 which a lot of people use - carelessly.

Comment: 0666 was just an example, I usually do 0600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_290.html, there is a function:

```
int chmod (const char *filename, mode_t mode)
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: how about using something like: open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)

Answer (score 2):

For user and group setting changes use the chown() function.  chmod() works on the st_mode values like protections and setuid, setgid, sticky bit.